# Assets CSS with Safecracker

Tags: assets, safecracker, css

Assets looks a bit wonky in a Safecracker form. See attached image. The image container gets calculated wrong.

[image]

Is there a different CSS file I have to reference when using Assets as a Safecracker field?

Template code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {exp:safecracker channel="items" return="add/next"}
    {field:item_temporary_photos}
    {/exp:safecracker}
    </body>
</html>
```

EE 2.6.1 / Assets 2.1.3

Comment: Hey Florian - it'd help to see your Safecracker template code. :) Thanks!

Comment: Hi, reduced template code added. Problem is still visible in a template that includes only these three lines of EE code.

Comment: I have the same issue, same version of EE/Assets http://f.cl.ly/items/3j1B0F1d121v1T343r0S/docs.jpg My template is the same, i just have include_jquery="no" as I use my own, but I tried without that too. I also have notification from plugin 'garnish' that says "Double-instantiating a context menu on an element". I see that popup info is also not positioned ok.

Comment: This appears to still be a problem in EE 2.9.2 (Channel Form) and Assets 2.5.

Comment: Hitting the same problem here